# What should we do to dynamically get a name entered in dialogflow and to get that stored in firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, chatbot, dialogflow-es

```
if(action === 'save.name' || inputContexts == 'welcome'){

  admin.firestore().collection('users').where('name', '==', Name).limit(1).get()
            .then(snapshot => {
                let user = snapshot.docs[0]
                if (!user) {

                    admin.firestore().collection('users').add({
                        name: Name
                    }).then(ref => {
                       console.log('Added new user');
                    });
                } else {
                    console.log('User already exists');
                }
            });
    }
```

I have a module of code for storing details in the firestore database which collects data from dialogflow bot, I don't know to how to refer that parameter("Name")entered in dialogflow? please help me out!

I tried--->>let name = app.getUser().Name;

but it doesn't work to get that name entered in dialogflow bot!

I am using api v1!

Comment: which  one APIv1 or v2 ?

Comment: **api v1** @Nikhil Savaliya

Comment: When you get data in your `req.body` try to debug from there there will be your parameters in contexts

Comment: Can you update your question to show which library you're using to handle fulfillment? (For example, how are you setting `action` in your code above?)

Comment: **const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
   
  let action = request.body.result.action;
these are libraries i have used before the module of code** @Prisoner

Comment: Please edit your question rather than try to put code in the comments. It makes it very difficult to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an Intent defined something like this:

[image]

then the parameter "name" will be available in your fulfillment through something like this:

```
var name = request.body.result.parameters.name;
```

Note that the parameter name is case sensitive, so if you call it "Name" in the console, you'd also call it "Name" in the expression here.

Comment: Thanks alot..Then how to get that "name" there in firebase code and save it in the database?Can you suggest me some sample code to get name and to store it in database ?

Comment: It looks like your code tries to do a save. Did that not work? If not, I'd post a new StackOverflow question with details of what you tried and what did or didn't happen.

Comment: This code worked! I defined name like the way you suugested and I assigned that name to a field and it worked! Thank you